# Stopping interval if a user clicks on a li

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery which works great, but i want to stop it emulating the clicks if a user actually clicks a tab...if anyone can help that would be great!

```
//Homepage Tabs
    $('#lcontent .tab:first').show();   
    $('#llist li').click(function() {

    var thisTop = $(this).position().top;
    $('.pointer').animate( {'top': thisTop} );

    $('#llist li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var id = $("li.current a").attr('href');
    $("#lcontent div").fadeOut(500).hide();
    $(id).fadeIn();
    return false;
});

setInterval((function(){
  var count = 0;
  var ul = $('#llist li');

  return function(){
    ul.eq(++count % ul.length).click();
  };
})(), 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check some properties from the `event object`, like the `originalEvent`:

```
var intervalID = null;

$('#llist li').click(function(event) {
   if('originalEvent' in event) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
   }
});

// ....

intervalID = setInterval((function(){
// ...
```

Some propertys, like `originalEvent` will appear within the event object, when triggered "normally". You still could emulate this, but I guess in your case this will be just fine.

Comment: Thank god for stackoverflow :)  You guys are very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` (and `setTimeout`) return an id you can use to stop the event.
Change your code like this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(...)
```

Then you can stop the interval wherever I like using

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Comment: I guess the question was more like, how to know when to stop.

Comment: THe trouble is i still would like it to start going through the tabs, and only stop when they click on a link!  This code unfortunately stops the initial slide through...

Comment: If you need *any* link inside *any* tabs to stop change the selector `$('#llist li a').click(function() clearInterval(intervalId); })`

Comment: Thanks keeper, i opted for Andys solution, but im sure this would have done the trick!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

```
//assign interval to a variable
myInterval = setInterval((function(){
  var count = 0;
  var ul = $('#llist li');

  return function(){
    ul.eq(++count % ul.length).click();
  };
})(), 3000);

//then in a click event handler for a tab
myInterval=clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input michal, i didnt get around to testing this but looks similar to andys, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearInterval` function, as [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval). I also would consider splitting up the 'click' into a custom event/bind.

```
var autoToggleInterval = setInterval((function(){
  var count = 0;
  var ul = $('#llist li');

  return function(){
    ul.eq(++count % ul.length).trigger('tabs:show');
  };
})(), 3000);

$('#lcontent .tab:first').show();

$('#llist li')
  .bind('tabs:show', function() {
    // your code
  })
  .click(function() {
    if(autoToggleInterval) {
      clearInterval(autoToggleInterval);
      autoToggleInterval = false;
    }
    $(this).trigger('tabs:show');
  });
```